# Sound is played in a loop without mouse or keyboard activity

Tags: 10.10, sound, pulseaudio

I have a weird problem with my linux.
if I run a mp3-file with the rhythm box or 
also run a video in youtube that results 
in that if I do not move my mouse or touch the keyboard for about 3 seconds,
the sound is played in a loop (the 2 last seconds keep repeating).
(In the case of youtube also the video stops in the meanwhile)
After touching the keyboard/mouse it repeats until nothing is pressed for around 3
seconds again!

Somebody knows this problem or a solution?

My distribution is Ubuntu 10.10 which uses pulseaudio.
I can kill it, but just by restarting it I get the same problem,
Do I need a different driver?

Comment: that's not a programming related question. I think it's difficult you will find here the solution at your problem. Anyway you should at least give some more details (It's a weird problem). Which distribution are you using? Is your software updated?...

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Overbose this isn't really a programming question, but if you're using a distribution that uses pulseaudio, try killing it and restarting it  using "pulseaudio -k" and "pulseaudio --check".

Comment: I have Ubuntu 10.10 and it seems it uses pulseaudio.